# Merge Dataframes with different number of rows

Tags: r

I am trying to merge together 8 dataframes into one, matching against the row names.

Examples of the dataframes:

DF1

|  | Arable and Horticulture |
| --- | --- |
| Acer | 100 |
| Achillea | 90 |
| Aesculus | 23 |
| Alliaria | 3 |
| Allium | 56 |
| Anchusa | 299 |

DF2

|  | Improved Grassland |
| --- | --- |
| Acer | 12 |
| Alliaria | 3 |
| Allium | 50 |
| Brassica | 23 |
| Calystegia | 299 |
| Campanula | 29 |

And so on for a few hundred rows for different plants and 8 columns of different habitats.
What I want the merged frame to look like:

|  | Arable and Horticulture | Improved Grassland |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acer | 100 | 12 |
| Achillea | 90 | 0 |
| Aesculus | 23 | 0 |
| Alliaria | 3 | 3 |
| Allium | 56 | 50 |
| Anchusa | 299 | 0 |
| Brassica | 0 | 23 |
| Calystegia | 0 | 299 |
| Campanula | 0 | 29 |

I tried merging

```
PolPerGen <- merge(DF1, DF2, all=TRUE)
```

But that does not match up the row name and dropped them entirely in the output

|  | Arable and Horticulture | Improved Grassland |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | NA |
| 2 | 90 | NA |
| 3 | 23 | NA |
| 4 | 2 | NA |
| 5 | 56 | NA |
| 6 | 299 | NA |
| 7 | NA | 12 |
| 8 | NA | 3 |
| 9 | NA | 50 |
| 10 | NA | 23 |
| 11 | NA | 299 |
| 12 | NA | 29 |

I am completely out of ideas, any thoughts?

Comment: The first column is variable? If not, create one with `rownames_to_column()` and the join should work

Comment: That did it, thanks @ViníciusFélix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset is,

```
dat1 = data.frame("Arable and Horticulture" = c(100, 90,23, 3, 56, 299), 
                  row.names = c("Acer", "Achillea", "Aesculus", "Alliaria", "Allium", "Anchusa"))

dat2 = data.frame("Improved Grassland" = c(12, 3, 50, 23, 299, 29), 
                  row.names = c("Acer", "Achillea", "Allium", "Brassica", "Calystegia", "Campanula"))
```

As @Vinícius Félix suggested first convert rownames to column.

```
library(tibble)
dat1 = rownames_to_column(dat1, "Plants")
dat2 = rownames_to_column(dat2, "Plants")
```

Then lets join both the datasets,

```
library(dplyr)
dat = full_join(dat1, dat2, )
```

And replace the `NA` with `0`

```
dat = dat %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)

      Plants Arable.and.Horticulture Improved.Grassland
1       Acer                     100                 12
2   Achillea                      90                  3
3   Aesculus                      23                  0
4   Alliaria                       3                  0
5     Allium                      56                 50
6    Anchusa                     299                  0
7   Brassica                       0                 23
8 Calystegia                       0                299
9  Campanula                       0                 29
```